# Redirect a particlular pattern of url through .htacess

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I need an rewite rule for a particlular pattern of url through .htacess in my blog site.See the situation is that a url contains categoryname  that need no be omitted for all such pattern of URLs to 301 redirect to new path

So the URL to hit
http://www.example.com/blog/whatever/prosper-life.html

and should be redirected to

http://www.example.com/blog/prosper-life.html

Is it possible through .htaccess? plz help

Comment: Is it always only **one** word (where ofcourse the word itself may change) which needs to be removed from the url?

Comment: @Rik_S its dynamic. It could be anything for any url

Comment: So it could also be something like /blog/bankruptcy/whatever/more/sub/parts/afile.html ?
Which needs to be rewritten to /blog/afile.html

Comment: @Rik_S No It should be /blog/whatever/more/sub/parts/afile.html  to
/blog/more/sub/parts/afile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no regex/htaccess expert by any means, but try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(\w)+\/{1}(.*)$ /blog/$2
```

I tested it out on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ with http://www.example.com/blog/your/bankruptcy/whatever/more/sub/parts/afile.html being the link, 
it removes the first sub-part.

It's just to show that it is, in fact, possible. There are probably better solutions out there.

Comment: its not working in .htaccess file although I tested it out on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ with http://www.example.com.com/blog/ask-gerri/collection-account-dispute.html and its not working there too. ask-gerri supposed to be ommited

Comment: first sub part should not contain hypenen(-) then its working

Comment: That's right. \w denotes word characters. You could use [\w\-] instead, so it works with `-`aswell, but when you match another special char it wont work again.